# Find or Create Multiple Records in Ruby on Rails - "find_or_create_all"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

What is an efficient and elegant way of performing a "find_or_create_all" in rails?

**Given:** 
names = ["Bob","John","Jack","Sid"],
 
Users table

**Needed:**
users = ["#User:0x3ae3a00", "#User:0x3ae3938", "#User:0x3ae3898", "#User:0x3ae37f8"]

where a user is created only if it doesn't exist.

An intermediate solution - ["#User:0x3ae3a00", nil, nil, "#User:0x3ae37f8"]  will also do, if for example only the first and fourth entries exist in the Users table.

One way is to use a find_all_by_name and use a hash to map back to the entries in the names array but I wonder if there is an elegant yet efficient way in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ar_extensions provides a good solution. https://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions

Assuming the table in question has a column with a unique database index, bulk inserts can be used to insert if there isn't a match on the unique column and skip or update the row if there is a match on the unique column.

Loading large datasets at envycasts covers this case http://envycasts.com/products/advanced-activerecord

Comment: I wanted to create multiple instances of a model in rails but I couldn't find a clean way to do it.But your link to ar-extensions gem was helpful.Thanks Sid

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 6 there is now [upsert_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/upsert_all) which I think handles this super well.

```
Book.upsert_all([
  { title: "Rework", author: "David", isbn: "1" },
  { title: "Eloquent Ruby", author: "Russ", isbn: "1" }
], unique_by: :isbn)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand and you want to take an array of names and convert it into an array of users?

```
names = ["Bob","John","Jack","Sid"]
users = names.map{|name| User.find_or_create_by_name(name)}
```

that will return an array of user objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem is that if the array is of length 1000, it will make 1000 separate queries to the DB. 

If something like this is being run in a cron job every 5 mins, it becomes inefficient.

The problem with making a single query i.e. find_all_by_name is losing the position within the array. One could use a hash to map back to the position in the array, but I am hoping there is an efficient & elegant way.

Comment: If the order is random and you want to keep it in the same random order, I don't know of a good way.  If there is some order based on a database table you can use `User.find(:conditions => {:name => names}, :order => column_name)`.  Or after the fact with sort_by http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120.

Comment: I would also check your database documentation to see if you can do something there by writing you own SQL.